# Convert and Display IP Address to Binary form?

Tags: c#

Is there a method in c# that would talk the ip address 10.13.216.41

and display it as 00001010.00001101.11011000.00101001.  If not, how can it be done?

Comment: I'm curious - why would one do this?

Comment: So I won't have to do it by hand.

Comment: I mean...why need the IP address in binary-ish format?

Comment: Oh, I was just messing around with using it with the subnet mask to get my host and network id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
static string IPAddrToBinary( string input) {
   // assumes a valid IP Address format
   return String.Join(".", (input.Split('.').Select(x => Convert.ToString(Int32.Parse(x), 2).PadLeft(8, '0'))).ToArray());
}
```

Here's a version with comments, which may be a *little* easier to understand:

```
static string IPAddrToBinary(string input)
{
    return String.Join(".", ( // join segments
        input.Split('.').Select( // split segments into a string[]

            // take each element of array, name it "x",
            //   and return binary format string
            x => Convert.ToString(Int32.Parse(x), 2).PadLeft(8, '0')

        // convert the IEnumerable<string> to string[],
        // which is 2nd parameter of String.Join
        )).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: What order is it calling the methods here?  i am not familiar with lambda syntax, so I am unsure.

Comment: Split -> Foreach -> Convert.ToString -> ToArray -> String.Join

Comment: Thanks Richard.  Still trying to get familiar with LINQ.

Answer (score 10):

While I won't rewrite the format-as-binary code (Larsenal's answer was fine), I'll point out that splitting on "." won't work for IPv6 addresses. If you use [IPAddress.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx), though, it will work for any address format. You can then use [IPAddress.GetAddressBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes.aspx) to get each part of the address.

So instead of:

```
input.Split('.').Select( ... )
```

do:

```
IPAddress.Parse(input).GetAddressBytes().Select( ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you would need to get the number you want to convert to binary (using String.Split, for example).  Then, you can use an overload of the Convert.ToString method to return a string of the specified number in the specified base.  For example:

```
Convert.ToString (128, 2);
```

returns

```
10000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I wrote a javascript version of this today for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503893/validate-ip-address-is-not-0-0-0-0-or-multicast-address/1504028#1504028).

Here's the c# translation of that code:

```
int dottedQuadToInt(string ip)
{      
    var parts = ip.Split(new char[] {'.'}, 4);
    if (parts.Length != 4) return -1;

    var result = 0; 
    var bitPos = 1;

    foreach(var part in parts)
    {
       //validation
       if (part.Length == 0 || part.Length > 3) return -1;

       int segment;
       if (!int.TryParse(part, out segment) || segment<0 || segment > 255) return -1;

       //compute next segment
       result += bitPos * segment;
       bitPos  = bitPos  << 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, this isn't exactly what you asked for, but it's arguably more useful and it shoudl point you in the right direction.

Comment: Just because it's more useful he should use it? Not trying to be a troll, but you have gold-plated the functionality he asked for. Additionally, it returns an int, and not a string.

Comment: This translation is not complete it seems.  TryParse does not take only 1 argument and base is a reserved keyword in c#.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var parts = (from p in ("10.13.216.41").Split('.')
              select int.Parse(p)).ToArray();
string result = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
    Convert.ToString(part[0], 2).PadLeft(8,'0'),
    Convert.ToString(part[1], 2).PadLeft(8,'0'),
    Convert.ToString(part[2], 2).PadLeft(8,'0'),
    Convert.ToString(part[3], 2).PadLeft(8,'0'));
```

Comment: I can't find the split method on string.  It doesn't popup with intellisense.

Comment: You updated it as well because I was able to use split on a variable of type string, but not directly on the string type.

Answer (score 0):

This method can help you:

```
static string IPDecToBinary(string IPAdresa)
{
    string IPverBinare = null;
    IPAddress IPDec = IPAddress.Parse(IPAdresa);
    byte[] IPByte = IPDec.GetAddressBytes();

    IPverBinare = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
                                 Convert.ToString(IPByte[0], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'),
                                 Convert.ToString(IPByte[1], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'),
                                 Convert.ToString(IPByte[2], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'),
                                 Convert.ToString(IPByte[3], 2).PadLeft(8, '0')
                                 );
    return IPverBinare;
}
```