# REGEX for Multicast IP Address

Tags: asp.net, regex, ip-address, multicast

I have gone through this wonderfull post on stackoverflow

[Validate IP address is not 0.0.0.0 or multicast address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503893/validate-ip-address-is-not-0-0-0-0-or-multicast-address)

But this is a custom javascript function which i have to write in my aspx page, instead of this is there any regex equivalent which could be helpful to validate the multicast ip-address

e.g. multicast IP address between 224.0.0.1 and 239.255.255.255

Thanks in advance for your efforts. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally I'd use math, but if you really want a regex,

```
^2(?:2[4-9]|3\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d?|0)){3}$
 <---|------|-->        <-----> <------> <---> <------> |  |
     |      |           |       |        |     |        |  three more octets
     |      |           |       |        |     |        |
     |      |           |       |        |     |        0
     |      |           |       |        |     |
     |      |           |       |        |     1 - 99
     |      |           |       |        |
     |      |           |       |        100 - 199
     |      |           |       |
     |      |           |       200 - 249
     |      |           |
     |      |           250 - 255
     |      |
     |      230 - 239
     |
     224 - 229
```

Comment: ahmm, thats really stunning regex for me, i would really thankfull to you to put your time on this. let me check and validate whether this regex works or not. +1 to you. :)

Comment: This answer is extremely close, but 224.123.123.256 will match it. It needs a $ at the end. So it should be 2(?:2[4-9]|3\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d?|0)){3}$

Answer (score 1):

Best solution will be to port javascript code from here: [Validate IP address is not 0.0.0.0 or multicast address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503893/validate-ip-address-is-not-0-0-0-0-or-multicast-address) to c#. Regular expressions are not suited to check ranges of numbers. You can write regular expression that covers all the possible combinations of numbers, but result will be huge and ineffective.