# IP Address validation for 0-255 and dot in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate IP address is not 0.0.0.0 or multicast address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503893/validate-ip-address-is-not-0-0-0-0-or-multicast-address)
>   [javascript regular expression to check for IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460586/javascript-regular-expression-to-check-for-ip-addresses)

I need to perform IP Address validation that should accept 0-255 number range and dots.

I am trying with this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function checkValid(eleValue) {

      if(!eleValue.match(/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/))
      {
         alert('Please enter Only Number or Dot');
      } 
   }
</script>

<input type="text" onkeyup='javascript:checkValid(this.value);' />
```

But its not working for me..

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following regex

```
/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/i
```

e.g.

```
/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/i.test('111.170.0.1') === true
```

Comment: @zerkms what are exactly the problem ?, pat.test('001.001.125.255') >> true

Comment: or right, your one will pass it, sorry

Comment: I use `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])` for 0-255 validation. It's basically `250-255 | 200-249 | 100-199 | 10-99 | 0-9`.